# passing parameter in function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to pass parameter in function `Myfunction()`.I want to pass 1) php value 2) `this.value` 3) `document.getElementById("rec")` in a same function.
If I pass only `this.value` as parameter function called successfully and passed to jquery-ajax page but I have problem with passing three or two parameter at a time. If I tried to pass in action using jquery Its also not working.
`document.getElementById("rec")` and  `var eid=$("#rec").val();` is not working.

```
echo '<form method="post">';
 $rec="select * from recruiter where comp_id='$comp'";
               $rec1=mysql_query($rec);

               echo '<select class="rec" id="rec" name="e_first_name" style="width:155px;" required onchange="myFunction(this.value);">';
               echo '<option value="" selected>Select Recruiter</option>';
               while($rfet=mysql_fetch_assoc($rec1))
               {
                 echo '<option value="'.$rfet["e_id"].'">'.$rfet["e_first_name"].'</option>';
               }
               echo '</select>';


               echo '<input type="text" name="dob" style="width:155px;display:none;"  id="datepicker1" placeholder="Choose Date" size=18 maxlength=50>';
               echo '<select name="report" style="width:155px;" class="report"  onchange="myFunction(this.value);">
               <option selected> Select Filter</option>
               <option value="datz">By Date</option>
               <option value="week">By week</option>
               <option value="month">By month</option>
               </select>';
               echo '</form>';
               ?>
```

My function as given below

```
function myFunction()
 {   
  $("#pre").hide();
  var datz=$("#datepicker1").val();

  var filt=$(".report").val();

   var eid=$("#rec").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "query3.php",
        data: { action: eid,filter:filt,datz:datz},
        error: function(msg) {

        },
        success: function(text) {

            $(".refresh").html(text);          
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Just add parameter inside `myFunction(a){ console.log(a);}

Answer (score 1):

Add any parameter inside your function.

For example:

```
    function myFunction(a) {   

       $("#pre").hide();
       var datz=$("#datepicker1").val();
       var filt=$(".report").val();
       var eid=$("#rec").val();

        console.log(a + ' : ' datz + ' : ' + filt + ' : ' + eid);

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "query3.php",
            data: { action: eid,filter:filt,datz:datz},
          error: function(msg) {

          },
          success: function(text) {
             $(".refresh").html(text);          
         }
      });
    }
```

Comment: console.log(a); doesn't return anything.var datz=$("#datepicker1").val();
       var filt=$(".report").val() also not working

Comment: I've updated my answer. This will return all your values.

Comment: problem with <select name="report" style="width:155px;" class="report"  onchange=myFunction('.$rfet[e_id].');>
       <option selected> Select Filter</option>
       <option value="datz">By Date</option>
       <option value="week">By week</option>
       <option value="month">By month</option>
       </select>

Comment: It must be `this.value`

Comment: I already done like this onclick=demo('Open',".$req_id."); in textbox .Is it not possible in select box sir?

Comment: You can't passed that in your function because it is in another set of selects. But you can still access that in your function by using `document.getElementByID`